# LOGSTASH - how to serach single event for a pattern

Tags: logstash

Here is what I try to accomplish, I try to gather syslogs from routers and switches, here is example from one device

```
I 05/23/16 11:50:14 ports: port 14 is now off-line
I 05/23/16 11:49:38 ports: port 14 is now on-line
W 05/23/16 11:49:36 ports: port 14 PD Invalid Signature indication.
I 05/23/16 11:49:35 ports: port 14 is Blocked by STP
I 05/23/16 11:49:32 ports: port 14 is now off-line
I 05/23/16 11:49:26 ip: VLAN101: network enabled on 10.101.0.130
I 05/23/16 11:49:26 ip: VLAN101: changing IP address to 10.101.0.130
```

All I want to do now is to catch string like "is now off-line" and then send emial alert, second part will be using Kibana to go through all logs easily. I got Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana up and working, I see all logs coming through.

Logs will be flowing from multiple devices, different types so I just need to catch string I need, mark it and and based on it do some action, eg send email

Do I have to brake every syslog piece by piece?
Is there a function to search a log?

```
input {
     udp {
      type => "syslog"
      port => 514
     }
    }
filter {
    if [type] == "syslog" { 
      **check if the single sting( or strings from dictionary) exist in this message** 
      **if yes, mark it, tag it if not just send the raw event to elasticsearch**
    }
}

output {
     elasticsearch { **send all logs**
     }
    **if the event needs attention send alert** { 
     email {
      from => "myemail@somewhere.com"
      subject => "%{tagged_event}"
      to => "you@example.com"
      via => "mail"
      body => "Alert something something: %{@message}"
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways depending on the complexity of what you're matching.

`in` operator:

```
if [type] == "syslog" { 
    if "is now off-line" in [message] or "some other thing" in [message] {
        mutate { add_tag => [ "alertNeeded" ] }
    }
}
```

Regex `=~` operator:

```
if [type] == "syslog" { 
    if [message] =~ /is now (off-line|on-line)/ {
        mutate { add_tag => [ "alertNeeded" ] }
    }
}
```

And then in the output section

```
if "alertNeeded" in [tags] {
    email { ... }
}
```